# How, in Perl, can I watch for file changes, without polling but with timeout?

Tags: perl, timeout, cross-platform, blocking, polling

I'm using `File::ChangeNotify`, which permits (a) nonblocking check for changes, or (b) blocking wait for changes. What I'd really like is something in between: block and wait for changes, but return after a specified timeout. I don't want to poll, and I can't afford to block forever.

It would be nice if the `$watcher->wait_for_events` method had such a timeout parameter but it seems not to; perhaps it's too hard to implement cross-platform. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to handle timeouts is [alarm](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm) function. Something like this:

```
my $timeout = 10;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
    alarm $timeout;
    $watcher->wait_for_events;
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out handling here
}
```

Comment: Not that this is unix-specific, while File::ChangeNotify is portable. Unknown are the OP's and future reader's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop this somewhere, where Perl can find it and `File::ChangeNotify` will pick it up and use it.

```
package File::ChangeNotify::Watcher::WithTimeOut;

use strict;
use warnings;

use namespace::autoclean;

use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

use Moo;

has watcher      => ( is => 'rw' );
has sleep_cycles => ( is => 'rw' );
has timeout      => ( is => 'rw' );

sub BUILD 
{
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    $self->sleep_cycles( delete $args->{sleep_cycles} );
    $self->timeout( delete $args->{timeout} || 0 );
    $self->watcher( File::ChangeNotify::Watcher::Default->new( %$args ) );
}

sub wait_for_events 
{
    my $self   = shift;

    my $cycles  = $self->sleep_cycles || -1;
    my $timeout = $self->timeout + time; 

    while ( $cycles-- != 0 ) 
    {
        my @events = $self->watcher->_interesting_events;

        return @events if @events;
        return @events if $self->timeout && time >= $timeout;

        sleep $self->watcher->sleep_interval;
    }
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

You can then either specify `timeout` or `sleep_cycles` arguments which will return control to the caller when the `timeout` expires or the watcher has slept `sleep_cycles` times for `sleep_interval` seconds.

```
use lib qw(./lib);
use File::ChangeNotify;
use Data::Dumper;

my $watcher = File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher ( 
    directories => [ 'C:/Users/holli/testnotify' ],
    filter         => qr/\.(?:pm|conf|yml)$/,
    sleep_interval => 1,
#    sleep_cycles   => 10,
    timeout        => 5,
);

while ( 1 ) 
{ 
    my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events;
    print Dumper( \@events );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OP in the least. For this to help the OP, there would need to be a module that provide a mechanism to asynchronously checks for file changes. It would also need to be cancelable. But if such a module existed, the OP could simply use it directly.

Comment: @ikegami Now there is a module =)

Comment: Lot better. The OP said "I don't want to poll", but I believe  this just poles the object rather than the system. It should be cheaper, though it has the lack of responsiveness of polling.

Comment: Well if the OP does not want to poll, then they must use another module alltogether. The Default watcher does exactly the same thing: while (1) { check for updates; sleep }